# Error in XML parser with JDOM2 package in android studio (java)

Tags: java, android, xml, jdom-2

This code should convert `xml` to json and i got below error in the first of it.
`SAXBuilder` can't read `xml` file.

I use JDOM2 library in this code.

Java code:

```
package com.example.books_xmltojson;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edittext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edittext = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        // SAX builder 
        InputStream input = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.books);
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        try {
            Document doc = builder.build(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
                edittext.setText(e.toString());
      } 
   }
}
```

XML R.raw.books:

```
// Resources
<catalog>
   <book>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>

   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

The error:

org.jdom2.JDOMException: http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities feature http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities not supported for SAX driver org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First i had to implement `xercesImpl.jar` to my project.
Then i had to change the `SAXBuilder` as below:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder("org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser");
builder.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
```

And guess what, `ChatGPT` solved my problem step by step. it's amazing.